# can't define a udf inside pyspark project

Tags: python, pyspark, udf, apache-spark-ml

I have a python project that uses pyspark and i am trying to define a udf function inside the spark project (not in my python project) specifically in spark\python\pyspark\ml\tuning.py but i get pickling problems. it can't load the udf. 
The code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, log
test_udf = udf(lambda x : -x[1], returnType=FloatType())
d = data.withColumn("new_col", test_udf(data["x"]))
d.show()
```

when i try d.show() i am getting exception of unknown attribute test_udf

In my python project i defined many udf and it worked fine.

Comment: Is this just a typo in entering this into stack overflow, or is this in your code as well? `ltest_udf(` should be `test_udf(` right?

Comment: Try this, remove `returnType=`, just write it as `udf(lambda x : -x, FloatType())`

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your code. It isn't recognizing the datatype.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
```

Let me know if this helps. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't help. see my answer above but thanks anyway

Comment: Oh i see, I tried it in the shell and it wasn't recognizing the data type. So had to add that import. thanks for sharing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found it there was 2 problems

1) for some reason it didn't like the returnType=FloatType() i needed to convert it to just FloatType() though this was the signature

2) The data in column x was a vector and for some reason i had to cast it to float

The working code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, log
test_udf = udf(lambda x : -float(x[1]), FloatType())
d = data.withColumn("new_col", test_udf(data["x"]))
d.show()
```